# SQLite execute query and get result

Tags: android, sqlite

I have that query

```
    String queryMonthSize = "SELECT (julianday(Date('now')) -
    julianday(date('now','-1 month')) FROM "+ TABLE_STATISTICS;
```

Which on sqlite it will return me the difference of the two dates.

How can i execute it on the android code so that i will return me the numerical value of the string?

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation will be

```
queryMonthSizeIntValue = Integer.parseInt(queryMonthSize);
```

See the the static parseInt() method:

- http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Integer.html